# Double Slit and Self Interference of Electrons

Tags: electrons, double-slit-experiment

I have not been able to get a clear notion of how particle waves are different than photon waves.

So I'll take a different approach.

With a diffraction grating, light can be shifted from a beam to a planar wave through a procedure analogous to a phase-array radar system:

The light beam enters N double slits at a mildly obtuse angle (transverse to the grating direction), and more or less all of the energy (with some loss) winds up propagating in a transparent crystalline wave guide through the process of total internal reflection.

This effect will work even if you fire one photon at a time at the diffraction grating.

Therefore, this implies, through wave particle duality, that an electron-diffraction grating could be created which achieved the same result.  One electron at a time.

This implies that electrons must be capable of self interference.  And yet it seems like there is a belief out there that electrons fly along a physical path... and that the apparent self interference is "just" an illusion -- a probability established when the electron exits the double slit.

But if that is the case, an electron could not be phased via diffraction to fly in a particular direction without depositing some energy somewhere and collapsing the wave function.

I use this example because, in the case of the diffraction grating or "phased array", self interference of particles is relied on to achieve a non-newtonian, deterministic trajectory.

Therefore, it is impossible for an electron to be newtonian and non-newtonian and get "phased"; at the same time, it is impossible for any kind of "multi-universe" interpretation because the energy direction output by a phase array or diffraction grating is an extremely deterministic one to many to one function (a multiverse creation and collapse in a puny diffraction grating: I don't think so); and the electron is not interacting with virtual particles, as that would imply that a phase array would "wear out" a region of space in the sense that a laser's transmission through air can change over time because the air molecules are modified by the heat exchange.  We are left with a self interfering wave-particle duality.  Or so I thought.

Anyhow, it seems like a newtonian interpretation, a posteriori, yields no phased-array electron emitters.  No electron based diffraction gratings.  Seems unlikely... So which is it: do electrons become waves and collapse to particles when diffracted and detected?

Or are they always particles?

Comment: "[...] And yet it seems like there is a belief out there that electrons fly along a physical path... and that the apparent self interference is "just" an illusion -- a probability established when the electron exits the double slit." I have never heard that interpretation. Where did you get this idea?

Comment: @noah a prior question.  So it is true then, that the electron is indeed "self interfering" up until it recovers locality through some sort of decoherence process?

Comment: @noah or at least, that it is a standard, respectable position?

Comment: That is the interpretation I am familiar with, yes. We describe the electron by its wave function until it interacts with something (like a detector), at which point it collapses and acts like a particle. But not before that.

Comment: Dirac even stated "Each photon interferes _only_ with itself." This is because different photons are usually in different modes or uncorrelated. The same reasoning also applies to matter waves.

Comment: Accelerated electrons emit billions of photons. As the electrons travel from the slits to the detection screen they are bombarded and corralled by reflecting photons,  forcing the electrons to only hit certain locations. This can be shown mathematically to match the wave function but it’s a model that’s real and physical.

Comment: @BillAlsept Awesome, I will research this

Comment: @Chris Electrons emit photons, billions of photons form waves, Photons reflect and photons interfere with electrons. Beyond that you’re not gonna find much research on that model.

Comment: @BillAlsept No problem -- quality over quantity.  I still have to resolve that against the idea that particle holograms are viable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a composite of several questions, which is not generally acceptable here.  However:

An electron, or any other small massive particle, is "only" a wavefunction until it is detected.  It definitely can interfere with itself, just like a photon.

The big difference between "particle waves" and photons is that particle waves can move at any speed, while photons (in a vacuum) only move at the speed of light.

Electrons - even one at a time - definitely can form standing wave patterns and therefore diffraction gratings (though since an electron can be detected at only one point, it takes a LOT of electrons to form a usable diffraction grating).  The "standing wave" created by a single electron, single photon, etc., is not directly detectable; its existence can only be inferred from a large number of single-electron experiments.

Similarly, an electron can be diffracted by a grating: an array of nanoscale metal lines, for example. And, the diffraction can be described in terms of Huygens Principle just as for light waves.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to tighten up these questions.  Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Particles are not interfering, not even with themselves. It is the wave function that does the interfering. Particles are just detected with a probability determined by the wave function. You can only detect an integer number of particles.

Comment: Imho, the wave function is an abstraction that we have written down to explain the empirical observations.  In this sense, it requires what is known as an "interpretation."  The interpretation should be correct in as much as it guides an experimentalist to ask the right questions, and an engineer to anticipate the right technological achievables, practically speaking.  The wave equation doesn't actually allow for this.  An effective interpretation (a reason why or a sense of how) really is required.  And being correct at the interpretive layer is, thus, critical.

Comment: @Chris The wavefunction is the best explanation we have for interference phenomena at the single-particle level. And surely it allows to make predictions for the outcomes of measurements, so what interpretation do you mean it lacks?

Comment: @A.P. enough support to take another step forward.  So, my background is almost entirely math. But I believe that experiments drive physics.  So any math we come up with has to be linked with some sort of physicality (i.e. some material effect that we can probe, cause information exchange, energy exchange, etc.) that allows a meaningful "next experiment" to occur.   And so I feel like stopping at the wave function is giving up.   We've abstracted it, but we haven't related it back to physical terms.

Comment: @Chris Even energy is just an abstract idea which can't be measured directly. But still it's an accepted concept. The reason is simply that it's useful for explaining many observations – already in classical mechanics. But certainly it makes sense to question these concepts. Maybe sticking to them prevents us from constructing more fundamental theories.

Comment: @A.P. sort of what I am driving at is that, well, I personally am happy to say that "hey, let's assume the equations *are* physical, and go from there, explore the wave, explore the collapse as if they are physically real" rather than this "we are sure they are particles, but the math works so we accept it and wave our hands philosophically afterwards" mentality

Comment: @A.P. and one of the articles that made me adopt this mentality was the reference free hologram via pre-determined matrix inverse of a diffuse lens (https://www.photonics.com/Articles/A_Breakthrough_for_Reference-Free_Holography/a61878) which happens to be leveraging techniques that I know a lot about (outside the physics), and an article about maliciously seeding a quantum key system (a laser diode on a computer chip) by firing a polarized beam into the well from the outside.  When I thought about those articles, I started to form a belief that the waves are physically real

Comment: @A.P. (I don't remember the magic google words for the laser cavity tainting for jamming quantum key distribution systems)

Answer (score 1):

One major point to bear in mind is that photons are massless particles so they get special treatment, an electron has mass.

Both have wave properties, it's OK for a mass particle to have wave properties but it is mysterious! Since the photon is massless it is easier to imagine it as a wave in the EM field but according to the Standard Model it is a particle because of how it fits in the model (I don't know the details why).

Why? How? does an electron have and show its wave properties is also a result of the EM field.  Firstly an electron will diffract and will self "interfere" and will produce the fringe pattern.  The word "interference" is historical and somewhat inaccurate when compared to modern theories like Feynman's.  Feynman postulated that photons consider all paths and eventually choose the shortest "allowed" path that is an integer multiple of its wavelength (resonant). Before a photon is even emitted its source electron is already disturbing the EM fields thru the use of what are called virtual photons, another particle of the Standard Model. An electron can stay in an excited state for a longish time, when the virtual field is right, energy in the form of the traditional photon is transferred all via the EM field.  An electron before its emission is also emanating virtual forces into the field, it also finds its most probable path of "allowed" paths based on wavelength.

It is the virtual fields that are tuned by diffraction gratings and slits that give the electron and photons certain paths. In the photon DSE all the photons that pass the slits end up in the bright areas, there are no photons in the dark bands.

Comment: that is really interesting -- I'll have to read this over a few more times

Comment: So I've listened to the Feynman lectures on physics -- specifically the one regarding electrons and the double slit -- a half dozen times.  It forms the basis of my understanding.  I don't recall the many path idea, or the pilot waves, or field theory entering into the picture.  And in his lecture on transistors, he specifically characterized electron indeterminacy (probability amplitudes) as, directly, a fluid.   Can you tell me more about when he had these ideas?

Comment: Google "Feynman Lecture Path Integral" deep into it ....." But if you can find a whole sequence of paths which have phases almost all the same, then the little contributions will add up and you get a reasonable total amplitude to arrive. The important path becomes the one for which there are many nearby paths which give the same phase.

Comment: Pilot waves are from Bohm[sp?] theory .... virtual photons are used to explain static EM forces like two magnets attracting.  In general the "interference" word is very historical and works well at the high school level, of course 2 photons cancelling is a violation of conservation of energy.  Using the EM field is not to be confused with advanced field theory where all particles arise from fields, EM field can be treated classically but waves must resonant like a piano string, i.e. paths or n times wavelength.

Comment: Virtual fields exist but they are another way of saying "probability fields" as when QM principles are appleid to the DSE. There is no energy in the dark areas, no photons, but you can argue that virtual fields cancel at these points.  I prefer to say the fields are strongest in the bright areas.  The use of virtual photons I have heard discussed on this website ... I do not have aa google reference as it pertains to "interference".